How to calculate an unnormalized solution x in HHL?
I'm going through this paper Step-by-Step HHL Algorithm Walkthrough, and wondering how to calculate an unnormalized solution $|x \rangle$ after measuring its b-register and ancilla qubit.
In equation (66), the state after applying IQPE is written as :
$| \psi_9 \rangle = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{\frac{8}{5}} \left( - \frac{1}{\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} }   | u_0 \rangle +  \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{2} }   | u_1 \rangle     \right) | 00 \rangle | 1 \rangle  $
As the probability of measuring $ | 0 \rangle_b | 1 \rangle_a$ and $ | 1 \rangle_b | 1 \rangle_a$ are $0.063$ and $0.564$ in FIGURE 4, is the solution $| x \rangle$ calculated as follows?
$| x \rangle = \frac{1}{\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{\frac{8}{5}}} \left( \sqrt{0.063}\|0 \rangle + \sqrt{0.564}\|1\rangle \right) $


In equation (66), the state after applying IQPE is written as :
$| \psi_9 \rangle = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{\frac{8}{5}} \left( - \frac{1}{\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} }   | u_0 \rangle +  \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{2} }   | u_1 \rangle     \right) | 00 \rangle | 1 \rangle  $
from equation (5),
$| x \rangle = \left( - \frac{1}{\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} }   | u_0 \rangle +  \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{2} }   | u_1 \rangle     \right)$
we can now rewrite $|\psi_9 \rangle$
$|\psi_9 \rangle  = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{\frac{8}{5}} | x \rangle | 00 \rangle | 1 \rangle  $
Let $P_{01}$ and $P_{11}$ be a probability that
$|0 \rangle $ and $|1 \rangle$ are stored in $b-register$ at the measurement. Then the norm would be
$norm = \sqrt{ \sqrt{ P_{01}}^2 + \sqrt{P_{11}}^2 }$
$\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{\frac{8}{5}} | x \rangle = \frac{1}{norm}\left( \sqrt{P_{01}}|0 \rangle + \sqrt{P_{11}}|1 \rangle \right)$
from the measurement result,
$P_{01} = 0.066$
$P_{01} = 0.565$
finally, we solve unnormalized $| x \rangle $
calculated $| x \rangle = 0.38352| 0 \rangle + 1.12212| 1 \rangle$
expected(classically solved) $| x \rangle = 0.375| 0 \rangle + 1.125| 1 \rangle$
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.visualization import plot_distribution
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
from qiskit.circuit.library import CUGate
import numpy as np
import math

from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session, SamplerV2 as Sampler

# hub = "ibm-q"
# group = "open"
# project = "main"

service = QiskitRuntimeService()


# In[2]:


clock_qubit_num = 2
b_qubit_num = 1
ancilla_qubit_num = 1
total_qubit_num = clock_qubit_num+b_qubit_num+ancilla_qubit_num

# Create the various registers needed
clockr = QuantumRegister(clock_qubit_num, name='clock')
br = QuantumRegister(b_qubit_num, name='b')
ar = QuantumRegister(ancilla_qubit_num, name='ancilla')
cr = ClassicalRegister(total_qubit_num, name='c')

# Create an empty circuit with the specified registers
circuit = QuantumCircuit(ar, clockr, br, cr)
circuit.barrier(label='$|\\psi_0\\rangle$')
circuit.draw(output='mpl')


# In[3]:


# apply inverse phase shift rotation gates in recursive 
def inv_qft_rotation(circuit, n, m):
    if n==0:
        return circuit
    # get theta index for rotation
    l = range(2, m-n+2)
    revl = list(l)[::-1]

    control_idx = 0
    n-=1
        
    for k in revl:
        circuit.cp(-np.pi/2**(k-1), control_idx, m-n-1)
        control_idx+=1
    circuit.h(m-n-1)
    return inv_qft_rotation(circuit, n, m)

# apply swap gates
def qft_swap(circuit, n):
    # num of times of swap
    swap_num = (int)(n/2)
    m = n-1
    for i in range(swap_num):
        circuit.swap(i, m)
        m -= 1 

# apply inverse qft transform
def inv_qft(n, m):
    qr = QuantumRegister(n)
    circ = QuantumCircuit(qr)
    qft_swap(circ, n)
    inv_qft_rotation(circ, n, m)
    U_g = circ.to_gate()
    U_g.label = f"IQFT(${m}$)"
    return U_g

# apply phase shift rotation gates in recursive 
def qft_rotation(circuit, n):
    if n==0:
        return circuit
    n-=1
    circuit.h(n)
    control_idx = n-1
    for k in range(2, n+2):
        circuit.cp(np.pi/2**(k-1), control_idx, n)
        control_idx-=1
    return qft_rotation(circuit, n)

# apply qft transform
def qft(n):
    qr = QuantumRegister(n)
    circ = QuantumCircuit(qr)
    qft_rotation(circ, n)
    qft_swap(circ, n)
    U_g = circ.to_gate()
    U_g.label = f"QFT(${n}$)"
    return U_g

def qpe(circ, clock, target):
    #circuit.barrier()

    # U=e^{i*A*t}
    # CU decomposition parameters
    theta = np.pi / 2
    phi = -np.pi / 2
    lam = np.pi / 2
    gamma = 3 * np.pi / 4
    
    cu_gate = CUGate(theta, phi, lam, gamma)
    circ.append(cu_gate, [clock[0], target])
        
    # U=e^{i*A*t*2}
    # CU decomposition parameters
    theta = np.pi
    phi = np.pi
    lam = 0
    gamma = 0

    cu_gate = CUGate(theta, phi, lam, gamma)
    circ.append(cu_gate, [clock[1], target])
    circuit.barrier(label='$|\\psi_3\\rangle$')

    #circuit.barrier();
    iqft = inv_qft(clock_qubit_num, clock_qubit_num)
    # Perform an inverse QFT on the register holding the eigenvalues
    circ.append(iqft, list(clockr))

def inv_qpe(circ, clock, target):
    # Perform a QFT on the register holding the eigenvalues
    circ.append(qft(clock_qubit_num), list(clockr))
    circuit.barrier(label='$|\\psi_7\\rangle$')
    
    # e^{-i*A*t*2}
    # U^2 = (U^2)^-1, thus e^{i*A*t*2} is used. 
    theta = np.pi
    phi = np.pi
    lam = 0
    gamma = 0
    cu_gate = CUGate(theta, phi, lam, gamma)
    circ.append(cu_gate, [clock[1], target])

    # e^{-i*A*t}
    # U^-1 != U, thus use the parameters as follows
    theta = np.pi / 2
    phi = np.pi / 2
    lam = -np.pi / 2
    gamma = -3 * np.pi / 4
    cu_gate = CUGate(theta, phi, lam, gamma)
    circ.append(cu_gate, [clock[0], target])
    circuit.barrier(label='$|\\psi_8\\rangle$')


# In[4]:


def hhl(circ, ancilla, clock, b, measurement):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()    
    qpe(circ, clock, b)
    circuit.barrier(label='$|\\psi_3\\rangle$')
    # This section is to test and implement C = 1
    circuit.cry(np.pi, clock[0], ancilla)
    circuit.cry(np.pi/3, clock[1], ancilla)
    circuit.barrier(label='$|\\psi_5\\rangle$')
    #circuit.barrier()
    
    circuit.measure(ancilla, measurement[0])
    circuit.barrier(label='$|\\psi_6\\rangle$')
    #circuit.barrier()
    inv_qpe(circ, clock, b)


# In[5]:


# State preparation. 
intial_state = [0,1]
circuit.initialize(intial_state, 3)
circuit.barrier(label='$|\\psi_1\\rangle$')

# Perform a Hadamard Transform
circuit.h(clockr)
circuit.barrier(label='$|\\psi_2\\rangle$')

hhl(circuit, ar, clockr, br, cr)

# Perform a Hadamard Transform
circuit.h(clockr)
circuit.barrier(label='$|\\psi_9\\rangle$')

#circuit.measure(ar, cr[0])
circuit.measure(clockr[0], cr[1])
circuit.measure(clockr[1], cr[2])
circuit.measure(br, cr[3])


# In[6]:


circuit.draw("mpl", fold=-1)


# In[7]:


#use a simulator for backend
aer = AerSimulator()
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=aer, optimization_level=0)
shots = 1000
isa_qc = pm.run(circuit)
with Session(backend=aer) as session:
    sampler = Sampler(session=session)
    result = sampler.run([isa_qc], shots=shots).result()

pub_result = result[0]
counts = pub_result.data.c.get_counts()
plot_distribution(counts)


# In[8]:


# refer to equation (66) in A Step-by-Step HHL Algorithm paper
NormCoeff = (2/3)*np.sqrt(8/5)


# In[9]:


#classically solve x
from numpy.linalg import solve
matA = [[1, -1/3],
        [-1/3, 1]]
vecB = [0, 1]
[classicX0, classicX1] = solve(matA, vecB)


# In[10]:


# Calculate probabilities
total_shots = sum(counts.values())
probabilities = {state: count / total_shots for state, count in counts.items()}
p_11 = probabilities['1001']
p_01 = probabilities['0001']
#print(p_11, p_01)

#normalize p_11, p_01, this could be right
k = np.sqrt(p_11 + p_01)
norm_sqrd_p_11 = np.sqrt(p_11)/k
norm_sqrd_p_01 = np.sqrt(p_01)/k


# In[11]:


#[x0, x1] = [round(np.sqrt(p_01)*(1/NormCoeff), 5), round(np.sqrt(p_11)*(1/NormCoeff), 5)]

#normalized version:
[x0, x1] = [round(norm_sqrd_p_01*(1/NormCoeff), 5), round(norm_sqrd_p_11*(1/NormCoeff), 5)]


# In[12]:


print("calculated solution [x] = ", [x0, x1])
print("expected solution   [x] = ", [classicX0, classicX1])


# In[ ]:



calculated solution [x] =  [0.38352, 1.12212]
expected solution   [x] =  [0.375, 1.125]

